# Search input in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am trying to implement a input/search-field in my website's navigation bar. I would very much like it to work like the YouTube navbar where the input-field is centered in between the left-side logo and links on the right side. But also such that the width of the input field is dynamic and compresses when the browser page is reduced in width.

I am not skilled in CSS and the only way I have been able to even make the search-field sit within the navbar is by setting the position to absolute (in the input-field class). I understand that you can accomplish the same outcome in multiple different ways with CSS and I know that fiddling with the position is properly the wrong way to go if it is also to be dynamic.

Please find a JSFiddle below and the html/CSS code. I am using MaterializeCSS to create the website and the 'brand-logo' class is used to center the logo when the browser window is below a certain threshold. I then use the class 'hide-on-med-and-down' on the ul to make the links disappear when the logo centers. However, I have removed the 'hide-on-med-and-below' class in the below JSFiddle to make it more apparent how the search input currently works.

https://jsfiddle.net/gwm6e031/19/

```
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">
        <div class="logo-text" href="#"><object href="#" class="logo-svg"></object>LOGO</div>
      </a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field hide-on-med-and-down">
      <input type="text" class="autocomplete z-depth-0" id="autocomplete-input" placeholder="Search.." />
    </div>
  </nav>
```

CSS code:

```
  body,
  html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  }

  /* Navigation bar */

  nav {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    z-index: 20;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
  }

  nav .nav-wrapper {
    padding: 0px 50px;
  }

  nav .logo-text {
    padding-top: 15px;
    font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
    font-size: 38px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-weight: bold;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  nav .logo-svg {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #fff;
  }

  nav .right {
  }

  nav ul a {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
  }

  nav ul a:focus {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }

  nav li a:hover {
    background: #006699;
  }

  /* Search bar TOP */
  nav .input-field {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 420px;
    width: 22%;
    max-width: 300px;
  }

  nav input {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif !important;
    height: 20px !important;
    background: #545a69 !important;
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(84, 90, 105, 0.9), rgba(84, 90, 105, 0.9)) !important;
    border: none !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    color: #fff !important;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px !important;
    padding-left: 15px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px !important;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px !important;
    border-radius: 5px !important;
  }
```

Comment: Does the structure of your HTML have to be in the same form as the example you've given or can it be changed?

Comment: I am open to all changes and edits! I have just tried to make this example be as close to the outcome I want as possible but I completely understand that some other setup can work better in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code, I have tried to write as simple as I can so you can easily change CSS parameters to your needs. (Take a look at HTML, there you will notice that I have moved position of input block code above ul list.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>title</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.css">
</head>
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,500,600,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
:root {
  --main-bg-color: #121a22;
  --main-bg-color-gradient: linear-gradient( rgba(18, 26, 34, 0.8), rgba(18, 26, 34, 0.8));
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
}

/* Navigation bar */
nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.nav-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    max-height: 50px;
}

.logo-text {
    display: flex;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    align-items: center;
}
.logo-svg {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.brand-logo {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.input-field {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: calc(100% - 600px);
}

input#autocomplete-input {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 700px;
    height: 30px;
}
.nav-wrapper ul {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.nav-wrapper ul li {
    list-style: none;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    transition: background-color .3s ease;
}
.nav-wrapper ul li:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
.nav-wrapper ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
<body>
    <nav>
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo">
          <div class="logo-text" href="#"><object href="#" class="logo-svg"></object>LOGO</div>
        </a>
        <div class="input-field">
            <input type="text" class="autocomplete z-depth-0" id="autocomplete-input" placeholder="Search.." />
        </div>
        <ul class="right">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>


</body>
</html>
```